Snowpark Procedure Async SQL Execution
I am trying to run a stored procedure in Snowflake written in Snowpark.
Wherein based on a list of tables I am running some SQL for each table.
I am trying to use the async feature to make the sql's run in parallel.
Tried this,
def run_sql_async(session, table_name,sql):
    result = session.sql(sql).collect(block=False)
    return result

And this,
def run_sql_async(session, table_name,sql):
    result = session.sql(sql).collect_nowait()
    return result

But apparently its not working. Based on query_history the sql's are still running in sequence.
I had another soln where I was using same collect_nowait wherein I was running CREATE statements using that. It did work for that use case from a snowpark procedure.
Are DML not supported by collect_nowait? Or does the function has limited capabilities?
Any other alternatives?
#UPDATE
Tried to run a SQL SELECT SYSTEM$WAIT(10) in a loop using ASYNC. SQL submited asynchronously in parallel.
Tried to run CTAS operation for a list of tables in a loop using ASYNC. Here also sql submited asynchronously in parallel.
Tried to run COPY INTO for a list of tables in a loop using ASYNC. This doesn't run in parallel but sequentially only. Not sure if its a bug within Snowflake
